# Delphi - Intercepting RESTClient Errors

Tags: rest, delphi

I am trying to learn Delphi REST programming.  I have set up a simple application, using RESTClient, RESTRequest and RESTResponse.  Everything works fine and I get my data, if I am connected to my company's VPN.  That is what I would expect, as the URL is within the VPN.  When I am not on VPN, I am getting a generic error "REST request failed: Execution of request terminated with unknown error."  My question is:  How do I intercept this error?  I have tried putting the request in a TRY..EXCEPT block.  This only gives me debugger Exceptions of ENetHttpClientException.

Here is what I thought should work...

```
try
  RESTRequest2.Execute;
 except
     ShowMessage(IntToStr(RestResponse2.StatusCode) + ':' + RestResponse2.StatusText);
  end;
```

Comment: Isn't that your error (NetHTTPClientException) ?, I mean you can't reach your server out of the the VPN, that's the exception you have catched, what else do you expect to get ?.

Comment: @@Marc - I would expect an error, as I am not on VPN.  What I want to do though is substitute my own error for the user.  The given error is a really cryptic one... I don't want it to show.  I would rather have my own...

Comment: Don't the NetHTTPClientException serves you to catch and personalize that situation ?. Why don't you put your own ShowMessage within that exception section ?.

Comment: @@Marc - Potentially, but I am not calling it.  It is being called by RestRequest2.Execute...  How do I add an exception to it?  I already have an exception on the RestRequest.

Comment: Can you raise your own exception within that section ?, something like : on E: exception do if E is Exception then raise Exception.Create('My customized message');

Comment: I meant .... if E is ENetHttpClientException then ...., sorry.